# Help on symmetric matrices question

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I am having trouble coming up with the solution to a problem from the book "Schaums Outlines: Linear algebra"

The answer is in there, but not the solution

The question is, find a real symmetric 2 by 2 matrix A with eigenvalues $\lambda =1$ with eigenvector $u=(1,1)$ and $\lambda = 4$ ( eigenvector not given). And find a matrix B for which $B^{2}=A$

Here is what I know/have tried.

I know that in this case, the eigenvectors will be orthogonal and also linearly independent.

I know the matrix will be of the form $$A= \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ and I actually saw my plugging in the definition that I will get a=c as well.

I tried just using $Au= \lambda u$ and plugging in and also tried finding the nullspace of the matrix given by $\lambda I - A$ but I can't seem to get it!

Can anyone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that fact that every symmetric matrix can be diagonalized by $A = TDT^T$, where $T$ is an orthogonal matrix with the eigenvectors as columns.

You know that the normalized vector
$$\hat u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
will have eigenvalue 1.
And you know that the normalized vector $\hat v$ which is orthogonal to $\hat u$ will have eigenvalue 4. You can find the vector $\hat v$ by
$$0 = \langle \hat u , \hat v \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}v_1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}v_2$$
from which you get $v_1 = - v_2$, hence $\hat v$ can be (another possibility is to reverse the signs of the components):
$$\hat v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
hence $T$ becomes:
$$T = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and you can calculate your matrix as:
$$TDT^T =
T \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix} T^{T} =
\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 5 & -3 \\ -3 & 5 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The matrix $B$ is then given by
$$B = T\sqrt{D}T^T = T \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{4} \end{pmatrix} T^T$$
since (note that $T^T = T^{-1}$ for orthogonal $T$):
$$B^2 = (T\sqrt{D}T^T)(T\sqrt{D}T^T) =  T\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}T^T = TDT^T = A.$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Why the downvote?